# Decrement loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run this loop

```
var max_number= $("input[name='max_number']").val(); 
var min_number= $("input[name='min_number']").val(); 

for(var j=max_number;j>=min_number;j--)
{  
  console.log('j value' + j);
}
```

`max_number is 10` & `min_number is 8` then for loop is not executing
when i change it to `j=max_number-1`

```
for(var j=max_number-1;j>=min_number;j--)
{  

    console.log('j value' + j);
}
```

but i want to start it with `max_number`

i want that loop should be executed like this :

if max_number is 12 and min number is 2
Output :

> 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2

Any solution, Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're dealing with ints?

Comment: `val()` will return a string. Convert them to numbers before trying to use in a loop